# How to determine the type of singularities in affine varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory

Let $X$ be the affine variety in $\mathbb C^3$ (coordinates $a, b, c$) defined as the zero set of $ac - b^2$. The variety has a "double point singularity" at the origin.

This is somewhat intuitive, but I don't know how to make sense of singularities for more complicated examples.

For example, let $Y$ be the affine variety in $\mathbb C^4$ (coordinates $a, b, c, d$), defined by $ac - b^2$ and $bd - c^2$.

What kind of singularities does this have?

Comment: In general, one does not talk about singularities of non-irreducible varieties, which your example is one. At any rate, when you ask 'what kind of...' you may not get a reasonable answer.